# Pandas ExcelWriter Appending to an Existing Worksheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

new_path = "testing.xlsx"

with pd.ExcelWriter(
    new_path,
    mode = 'a'
    ) as writer:
    notes_df.to_excel(
        writer,
        sheet_name = "Lunch Menu",
        header=True,
        freeze_panes=(1,0)
        )
```

Instead of appending to the "Lunch Menu" worksheet, it adds another worksheet named "Lunch Menu".

How can I get this to append to the same worksheet?

Documentation for the `to_excel` function:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Documentation for `ExcelWriter`:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter

Comment: You need to show the code for the to_excel() function. And what are the pd and notes_df modules ? Please have a loot at [this page] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular that part about helping others reproduce the problem.

Comment: notes_df is a dataframe. It doesn't matter what is in it. It can have any data columns you would like.

pd is standard shorthand for the pandas library. I edited my original post.